# JQuery, как удалить все option из select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select onchange="myFun(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
  </select>

  <legend>Поиск</legend>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Искать"></p>
</form>

<script>
  function myFun(id) {
    $('#mySelect').find('option').remove();
  }
</script>
```

После выбора любого пункта из первого селекта, значения из второго не изменяются - точнее в отладчике они удаляются, а в форме нет.
Тоже происходит и при попытке добавить новые пункты во второй селект.

Как быть?

Comment: Все работает как у вас и написано- При любом изменении ПЕРВОГО селекта - удаляются ВСЕ опшены из второго

Comment: Здесь да, но на моей странице нет

Comment: Так сделайте на своей странице так как здесь. Или пример который Вы привели не достаточно полный?

Comment: Так, у меня тут Materialize еще - сейчас попробовал его отключить и без него вроде работает. Но я не хочу его совсем отключать, он мне нужен

Answer (score 0):

> в отладчике они удаляются, а в форме нет

Так не бывает. У Вас на странице несколько элементов с `id="mySelect"`.

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод `.empty()` для очистки контейнера:

```
 $('#mySelect').empty();
```